# обратиться к значению prompt

Tags: javascript

Если вводить значения в prompt через пробел (Вася Петя Саша), как сделать массив значений и обращаться непосредственно к определенному элементу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const quest = prompt();
const arr = quest.split(' ');
console.log(arr[1]);
```